# How to add multiple variables to matplotlib tittle

Tags: matplotlib

I want to add 2 variables to my tittle of matplotlib graph, i have no problems printing only 1 variable:

```
plt.title('Validation RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

But when it comes to printing 2 variables i dont get ir right,

I've been trying things like this:

```
plt.title('Validation RMSE: %.3f MAE: %.3f' % rmse % mae)
```

But it doesnt seem to work, could someone please help me printing 2 variables in 1 line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose them in round brackets. See the following example

```
rmse = 1.45656
mae = 0.23456

plt.title('Validation RMSE: %.3f MAE: %.3f' %(rmse, mae))
```

Alternatively, you can also write it using `format` as

```
plt.title('Validation RMSE: {:.3f} MAE: {:.3f}'.format(rmse, mae))
```

Or as suggested by [Jody Klymak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3394386/jody-klymak) in the comments, if you have recent python version

```
plt.title(f'Validation RMSE: {rmse:.3f} MAE: {mae:.3f}')
```

[image]

Comment: Or if you have a recent python, use an f-string: `plt.title(f'Validation RMSE: {rmse:.3f} MAE: {mae:.3f}')

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for the comment. I have added your suggestion to the answer and acknowledged you.